# NodeJS vs Laravel with Mysql Database which one better in term of performance

Tags: mysql, node.js, laravel, performance, load-balancing

I am developing a REST Back-End with MYSQL database,now i need to choose between which server side language its better in term of less server resources (CPU and Ram) consuming .

Let say for example, i have a POST end point for (register a new user account) and another GET end point for (getting the user info in JSON format). and i am expecting a high traffic on my website, which programming language will consume more server resources ?

I have googled to compare between both NodejS and Laravel, i found some websites showing a benchmark test with a favor of laravel and other website showing that NodeJS is better.

Comment: How many such queries per minute?

Comment: @RickJames it can reach 7000+ per minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With basic get/set DB operations there isn't going to be significant time in whichever language you choose.

Choose a language based on non-performance criteria and solve specific performance problems as they arise.

As you've tag load-balancing I assume you application is already horizontally scaleable.

Comment: Yes, regarding the load-balancing i will host my website in AWS with setting an application load balancer with auto-scalling . but as you know, AWS will charge more if new instance is initiated. My concern is , if nodeJS is consuming less as what others said, that mean it's less potential, the need of aws autoscale to initiate a new instances and cost more.

Comment: write the application both ways and benchmark it yourself is the other way. Ensure you have the backend data MySQL right (ask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/) as its likely to be the larger consumer of resources.

Comment: Sure, its good idea as you said, i will write on both programming language then i will benchmark by sending a loop of http requests.

Answer (score -2):

I built myself sql script writer like this, it's pretty fast for my project since my previous PHP Backend is too slow (in my case)

```
const mysqlLib = require('mysql');
const ENV = require('../configs/env').ENV;
const database = ENV.database;
const mysql = mysqlLib.createPool(database);

function executeQuery(query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mysql.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(query);
                return reject(err);
            }

            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}

function executeQueryGetFirst(query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mysql.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(query);
                return reject(err);
            }

            result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));

            if (result.length == 0) {
                resolve(null);
            } else {
                resolve(result[0]);
            }
        });
    });
}

var Database = {
    getById(table, id) {
        var query = '';
        query += 'SELECT * FROM ' + table + ' ';
        query += 'WHERE Id = ' + id;
        query += ' LIMIT 1';

        return executeQueryGetFirst(query);
    },
    getAllById(table, id) {
        var query = '';
        query += 'SELECT * FROM ' + table + ' ';
        query += 'WHERE Id = ' + id;

        return executeQuery(query);
    },
    getByAttributes(table, attributes) {
        var query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + table;
        var whereQuery = '';

        for (prop in attributes) {
            if (whereQuery != '') {
                whereQuery += ' AND ';
            }

            if (attributes[prop] == null) {
                whereQuery += prop + ' IS NULL';
            } else {
                whereQuery += prop + ' = "' + attributes[prop] + '"';
            }
        }

        query += ' WHERE ' + whereQuery;
        query += ' LIMIT 1';

        return executeQueryGetFirst(query);
    },
    getAllByAttributes(table, attributes) {
        var query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + table;
        var whereQuery = '';

        for (prop in attributes) {
            if (whereQuery != '') {
                whereQuery += ' AND ';
            }

            if (attributes[prop] == null) {
                whereQuery += prop + ' IS NULL';
            } else {
                whereQuery += prop + ' = "' + attributes[prop] + '"';
            }
        }

        query += ' WHERE ' + whereQuery;

        return executeQuery(query);
    },
    getAll(table) {
        var query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + table;

        return executeQuery(query);
    },
    add(table, attributes) {
        var insertName = '(Id';
        var insertData = '(NULL';

        for (prop in attributes) {
            var value = attributes[prop];
            if (value != null) {
                value = '"' + value + '"';
            }

            insertName += ', ' + prop;
            insertData += ', ' + value;
        }

        insertName += ')';
        insertData += ')';

        var query = 'INSERT INTO ' + table + ' ' + insertName + ' VALUES ' + insertData;

        return executeQuery(query);
    },
    updateByID(table, id, attributes) {
        var query = 'UPDATE ' + table;
        var setQuery = '';

        for (prop in attributes) {
            if (setQuery != '') {
                setQuery += ', ';
            }

            setQuery += prop + ' = "' + attributes[prop] + '"';
        }

        query += ' SET ' + setQuery + ' WHERE Id = ' + id;

        return executeQuery(query);
    },
    updateByAttributes(table, findAttributes, attributes) {
        var query = 'UPDATE ' + table;
        var setQuery = '';
        var whereQuery = '';

        for (prop in attributes) {
            if (setQuery != '') {
                setQuery += ', ';
            }

            setQuery += prop + ' = "' + attributes[prop] + '"';
        }

        for (prop in findAttributes) {
            if (whereQuery != '') {
                whereQuery += ', ';
            }

            whereQuery += prop + ' = "' + findAttributes[prop] + '"';
        }

        query += ' SET ' + setQuery + ' WHERE ' + whereQuery;

        return executeQuery(query);
    },
    deleteById(table, id) {
        var query = 'DELETE FROM ' + table + ' WHERE Id = ' + id;

        return executeQuery(query);
    },
    deleteByAttributes(table, attributes) {
        var query = 'DELETE FROM ' + table;
        var whereQuery = '';

        for (prop in attributes) {
            if (whereQuery != '') {
                whereQuery += ' AND ';
            }

            whereQuery += prop + ' = "' + attributes[prop] + '"';
        }

        query += ' WHERE ' + whereQuery;

        return executeQuery(query);
    }
}

Database.executeQuery = executeQuery;
Database.executeQueryGetFirst = executeQueryGetFirst;

exports.Database = Database;
```

Env config

```
var ENV = {
    isDev: true,
    database: {
        connectionLimit: 10,
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'your_database'
    }
}

exports.ENV = ENV;
exports.ENV.port = ENV.isDev ? 15001 : 8887;
```